# Pointwise and uniform convergence of function series $f_n = x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm asked to prove whether the following function-series

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ on $E$ with values in $Y$ converges pointwise/uniformly/absolutely.

$$E = [0, 1), Y= \Bbb{R}$$
$$f_n = x^n$$

What I have tried so far:

According to the [Weierstrass M-Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) $f_n$ is not convering absolutetly (if I didn't produce any mistakes.)

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}\frac{1}{1-x}
$$
because $\left|x\right|<1$. Hence it converges pointly.
Furthermore it is the same for $\left|x\right|$ because $\left|x^k\right|=\left|x\right|^k$. Hence it is absolutely convergente.

$$
\sum_{k=p+1}^{N}x^k=x^{p+1}\frac{1-x^{N-p}}{1-x}
$$
So
$$
\sum_{k=p+1}^{+\infty}x^k=x^{p+1}\frac{1}{1-x}$$
For $x \in \left[a,b\right], \ a<b$ with $\left(a,b\right) \in \left[0,1\right[^2$ we have
$$
\left\|\sum_{k=p+1}^{+\infty}x^k\right\|_{\infty,\left[0,b\right]} \leq b^{p+1}\underset{p \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0
$$
So it also converges uniformly on every compact set of $\left[0,1\right[$.

Comment: It does converge uniformly on compact subsets as you say. I would like to caution the OP in saying that this doesn’t mean uniform convergence over $[0,1)$.

Comment: But doesn't absolute convergence imply uniform convergence? @Joel

Comment: Absolutely not, careful

Comment: @m4rkus Absolute convergence does not imply uniform convergence.